# What does "localizer level flight" in the approach checklist mean?

Tags: terminology, pilots, approach, checklist

What does "localizer level flight" in the approach checklist mean?

How might an actual dialogue in the cockpit sound when the approach checklist is executed? Are the words "localizer level flight" actually said aloud? If so, what is said in response to them?

I.e.

> "Localizer level flight." (?)
>
> "???"
>
> "Fasten seat belts."
>
> "On." (?)

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have the full checklist?  Where did you get this excerpt from?  Can you post a link or screenshot?  (*most checklists delineate by font, italics, etc. what the verbal challenge and response elements are.  It would be a lot easier to decode with an example for context.*)

Comment: Something like this: https://www.scribd.com/document/179167779/Boeing-737-200-Checklist

Comment: For what it's worth, that "checklist" has many severe issues and bears scant resemblance to what's actually used in 737 operations. The term "localizer level flight" isn't a standard term, and several of the items listed under that heading really need to have been accomplished ***long*** before intercepting the localizer. I'd recommend ignoring that document and finding a better source.

Comment: @RalphJ Thank you for letting me know. By any chance, do you know where I might find a more legitimate example of an approach checklist?

Comment: @RalphJ Does this look better? https://ibb.co/xFWY1cb

Comment: That looks less awful, but it's for a different aircraft, and some of the items are still pretty clumsy. What's the source of all of these documents? If they're coming from an internet search, please realize that the search engines have no judgement about quality; they'll just return things that call themselves checklists that have been linked some number of times. For something close to what Boeing recommends, see [here](http://www.b737.org.uk/nnp.htm).

Comment: The source is just me doing Google searches for different combinations of words... I don't need it to be for a particular aircraft; this is for a hobby translation/writing project, and I'm mainly just trying to figure out 4 lines of plausible dialogue of pilots going through a checklist prior to landing, preferably with one of the items on the checklist being the fasten seat belts sign.

Answer (score 2):

Its the phase of flight when your established on the localizer but have not yet started your decent on the glide slope and are in level flight. In other words your utilizing the horizontal guidance component of the approach but have either not intercepted the glide slope yet or the needles are coming in and you are not yet at the point of descending. [This answer has a good description of intercepting the localizer.](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/42270/what-are-atcs-considerations-when-they-instruct-to-intercept-final-approach-cou)

For example lets say your coming into [KHPN on the ILS to 34](https://aeronav.faa.gov/d-tpp/2313/00651IL34.PDF). If you intercept outside of THEEO you will be straight and level but following horizontal guidance until you get to THEEO and thus will be following the localizer but in level flight.